# Tensorflow error "No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I built a new environment in conda using the following .yml file:

name: py37 channels:

- conda-forge
- defaults dependencies:
- python=3.7.7
- cartopy=0.18.0
- earthengine-api=0.1.221
- flake8=3.8.1
- jupyterlab=2.1.2
- jupyter_contrib_nbextensions=0.5.1
- matplotlib=3.2.1
- mypy=0.770
- nb_conda=2.2.1  # optional, useful for running R in Jupyter notebooks
- numpy=1.18.4
- pandas=1.0.3
- pillow=7.1.2
- scikit-learn=0.23.0
- scipy=1.4.1
- seaborn=0.10.1
- tqdm=4.46.0
- tensorflow=1.15.0  # only supports up to Python 3.7

I am now running the following section in a .ipynb file

```
from pprint import pprint import os import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import numpy as np import pandas as pd import tensorflow as tf

sys.path.append('../') from preprocessing.helper import get_first_feature_map, get_feature_types from utils.geo_plot import setup_ax
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in callback <bound method AutoreloadMagics.post_execute_hook of <autoreload.AutoreloadMagics object at 0x7fba286b3a50>> (for post_execute): Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/events.py", line 89, in trigger
    func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 538, in post_execute_hook
    _, pymtime = self._reloader.filename_and_mtime(sys.modules[modname])   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 184, in filename_and_mtime
    if not hasattr(module, '__file__') or module.__file__ is None:   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import compiler   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/compiler/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import jit   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/compiler/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/compiler/xla.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/estimator/model_fn.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/model_fn.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.types import core ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.types'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2077, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_() AttributeError: 'ModuleNotFoundError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 248, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 281, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)   File "/Users/prernamishra/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

Do I need to install anything else? The original yml file had - tensorflow==1.15.0 but I changed it because I am running it on a mac and that wasn't working.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please upgrade to tensorflow 2.c [2.7] and ensure python and OS is 64 bits.
Can you also try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

If the error persist:

Create an virtual environment

```
cd <your project path>

Install virtualenv

pip install virtualenv
```

Create the virtual environment

`virtualenv <envname`>

Activate the env

Windows Powershell: .<envname>\Scripts\activate
Unix with Bash or zsh: source /bin/activate
Then now you install tensorflow

```
(<envname>) $ pip install tensorflow
```

And then run Hello World successfully.

*Don't forget that you need to activate or configure everytime the virtual environment jupyter, command-line, etc.